# sprintf an unsigned char array

Tags: c, printf

I need to read IP addresses into a char array for working on it later. Since IP octets can be as big as 256, I thought it would be good to use unsigned char array to read them. This is how I intend to use it.

```
sprintf(buf,"%d.%d.%d.%d",ip24,ip16,ip8,ip);
```

But it appears that first argument of sprintf should be char* and hence it's throwing the below warning. How do I deal with it.

```
expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned char *’
```

Comment: why not initialize buf as a char array, big enough to handle an ip address? this way you dont need it to be unsigned:
`char buf[16]="255.255.255.255"`

Comment: What's irrelevant is that "IP octets can be as big as 256". So what? You're rendering them as a text string, which is made up of `char`s. This question indicates a lack of thought about what you're doing.

Comment: You haven't shown us, but `buf` is obviously the wrong type.  Declare it as a `char *` rather than an `unsigned char*`.  And depending on the type of `ip` and friends, you probably want to use `%u` rather than `%d` (and octets cannot be as large as 256; the valid range is [0,255]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `buf` should be `char*` in first place. The fact that an IP octet can be as big as 256 (that is it is a unsigned char) has nothing to do with the fact that `buf` is an array of `unsigned char`.

`sprint` wants a `char*` as first argument, so give it a char:

[**Live Demonstration**](https://www.ideone.com/eALJBw)

Answer (score 2):

```
sprintf((char*)buf,"%d.%d.%d.%d",ip24,ip16,ip8,ip);
```

this can avoid the warning. But why not use char* buf?

Comment: This answer is misleading, he just shouldn't use `unsigned char*` but `char*`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Many times it is not up to the code maintainer to choose the datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `buf` as a `char*` or `char buf[16]` instead of `unsigned char*`, or cast it when using, if changing the data type of `buf` is a hassle.

As you rightly stated, referring to the man page for [sprintf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf), it indicates that it expected the first argument of the type `char *str`.